# There is an issue with the API being called when toggling the sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// App.jsx
const App=()=>{
    ...
    const [showRightBar, setShowRightBar] = useState(true);
    ...
    const toggleSegmentsList = useCallback(() => setShowRightBar((v) => !v), []);

    // where the second argument to useCallback is an empty array or, 
    // Even with `[showRightBar]`, the api is still being called when clicking `FaAngleLeft`


    return (
        <>
            {showRightBar && (
        <SegmentList
          toggleSegmentsList={toggleSegmentsList}
        />
      )}
        ....
        {!showRightBar && (
      <FaAngleLeft
        title={t("Show sidebar")}
        onClick={toggleSegmentsList}
      />
    )}
    </>
    )
}
```

```
// SegmentList.jsx
useEffect(() => {
      const sendPostRequest = async () => {
        const postData = {
          filepath: filePath,
          clips: ["0-59.993"],
          frame: Number(frameValue),
          process: Number(processNumber)
        };

        const res = await postWithToastAndErrorHandling(postData); 
        if (!res) return;

        const { results } = res.data;

        return res.data.results;
      };
            
      const postWithToastAndErrorHandling = async (postData) => {
        try {
          return await axios.post(import.meta.env.apiAddress, postData);
        } catch (error) {
          toast.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Error",
          });
        }
      };

      const handlePostSegments = async () => {
          const res = await sendPostRequest();
        }
      };

      handlePostSegments();
    }, [segments]);

    // Empty array prevents apiAddress from being called on first video call
    // apiAddress is called when the FaAngleLeft button is clicked, even with an empty array
 // I tried treating the dependency array for useEffect in the SegmentList.jsx file as an empty array 
// or as [filePath, frameValue, processNumber], but the api is still being called on click FaAngleLeft.

    return (
        <AngleRightIcon
      title={t("Close sidebar")}
      role="button"
      onClick={toggleSegmentsList}
       />
    )
```

`segments` like this format
`[{end: 59.993,name: "", segColorIndex: 0,segId: "xxxx",start: 0,tags: undefined}]`

Something went wrong while toggling the SideBar.

The issue is that when I click on `AngleRightIcon` there is no response(it works fine),

but when I click on `FaAngleLeft` the api inside the `postWithToastAndErrorHandling` function is executed.

I believe that nothing should happen when toggling the SideBar, other than a re-render, whether clicking on the `AngleRightIcon` or `FaAngleLeft` icon.
I would like to know if I am doing something wrong in the above code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `app.jsx`, since you are creating/destroying the component (`SegmentList`) on toggle of the variable `showRightBar`, the useEffect is running again and again!

```
  {showRightBar && (  
    <SegmentList
      toggleSegmentsList={toggleSegmentsList}
    />
  )}
```

Instead can you try this?

```
<SegmentList
    hidden={showRightBar}
    toggleSegmentsList={toggleSegmentsList}
/>
```

Comment: `<SegmentList     hidden={showRightBar}     toggleSegmentsList={toggleSegmentsList} />` This will prevent the AngleRightIcon's onClick handler from working. showRightBar && must be added for it to work properly. Also, I checked the hidden prop you mentioned in the SegmentList and found that hidden is false on the first render, but when I clicked on FaAngleLeft and AngleRightIcon repeatedly, the hidden value is always true. Also, I've edited my post, could you please check it?